# How does migrationBuilder determine which indexes to create?

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

This is using asp.net core 2.0, EF, visual studio 2017, sql server 2016, and creating a db migration via package manager console using 'add-migration' tool within the Package Manager Console.

I have a simple many-to-many relationship configured as below, 2 tables and a third 'joining table':

```
public class TblTrack
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

     ...

    //Navigation properties
    public List<TblProductItem> ProductItems { get; set; }
}


public class TblProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...

    //Navigation properties
    public List<TblProductItem> ProductItems { get; set; }
}

public class TblProductItem
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int TrackID { get; set; }


    //Navigation properties
    public TblProduct Product { get; set; }
    public TblTrack Track { get; set; }
}
```

This is from the migration (generate in PMC) to create the joining table:

```
migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
name: "PK_tbl_ProductItems",
table: "tbl_ProductItems",
columns: new[] { "ProductID", "TrackID" });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
name: "IX_tbl_ProductItems_TrackID",
table: "tbl_ProductItems",
column: "TrackID");
```

Please could someone explain:

What's the purpose of the index `IX_tbl_ProductItems_TrackID`?

Why was an index created for `TrackID` but not for `ProductID`?

Is there some other setting that determines which indexes will be created in the migration?

Comment: I think this is too specific to the provider you're using. Which one ?

Comment: Indices are usually created in 3 cases by EF: 1) On any FK column, a clustered, non-unique index should be created; 2) On any PK column, a unique primary key constraint should be created, together with the relevant index; 3) Additional indices you've added through Fluent API or Data Annotations. The specific commands are generated by the EF provider obviously, if the general index creation comes from the context model or from the provider (as part of a subroutine), I'm unsure of.

Comment: Thanks, I added some details above. I guess I was surprised to see an index automatically created for TrackID but not ProductID - apart from referring to different tables the foreign keys are the same (and nothing in Fluent API) so why would it generate one but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default EF automatically creates Index (non-unique) on each property that is a foreign key reference.

Make sure that EF correctly created relation between `TblProduct` and `TblProductItem`(for example in SQL Server by expanding keys) - if not, specify relation explicitly using Fluent Api.

Regarding other setting you can require creating indexes using method in your Context class, but that index should be auto generated if foreign key relation is set.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TblProductItem>()
        .HasIndex(e => e.TrackID);
}
```

Comment: That's why I wondered why an index was automatically created for TrackID but not ProductID. The FK relations between tables have been created correctly. I can add the index using Fluent API but why did 'add-migration' not do that automatically? (or rather it did for one FK but not the other).

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same thing. I found out that if I reversed the order of the keys (using Fluent, however) it would make an index for the second column instead.

So to me, it seems like there's a bug in the framework when using composite keys. It is the ForeignKey annotation that causes the index to be made, but in this process it seems to believe that the primary key is the FIRST column only (in that case, no extra index needed for a "primary key" column), so it only creates an index for the second. But the primary key is composite, so it should probably create an index for the first column too.

A workaround (if you really want the first column to be indexed too) is to do what's suggested in the accepted answer. Should the bug (AFAIK) be fixed later, I don't think it would cause a problem by trying to create an extra index or anything.